# How to get return value of 0 in UDP recvfrom() call after shutdown call.?

Tags: c++, networking, udp

I have tried getting the value of 0 over the network when the socket connection has been gracefully closed by the sender as specified [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740120%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). When I used unblocked call I was getting -1 in the UDP stream before data was sent from sender to the receiver . After the original data was sent and when I closed the connection(tried shutting down the socket and closing the socket on the sender side) I was still getting -1 rather than getting 0 indicating the socket has been closed. can anybody please help is there is any way to get the same.

Thanks.

Comment: there is no concept of `connection` for UDP sockets

Comment: @aleguna   yes thats fine but what is the mechanism to get the return value of 0 from recvfrom() as mentioned in the documentation.

Comment: There is no such mechanism. And you can't shutdown a UDP socket. It's a TCP-only operation. Did you ignore a -1/errno result from shutdown()?

Comment: If you want a return value of 0 send a 0-byte length message.

Comment: However that just indicates a zero length message, not peer disconnection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When UDP socket is [`close(2)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/close.2.html)-ed there's nothing sent out, even if the socket was [`connect(2)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/connect.2.html)-ed. TCP, on the other hand, initiates [four-way connection tear-down](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#Connection_termination). Looks like you are confusing these two cases.

Answer (score 1):

UNIX man page for shutdown [states](http://linux.die.net/man/2/shutdown) the following:

> Return Value:
>
> On success, zero is returned. On error, -1 is returned,
> and errno is set appropriately.
>
> Errors:
>
> EBADF - sockfd is not a valid descriptor.
> ENOTCONN - The specified socket is not connected.
> ENOTSOCK - sockfd is a file, not a socket.

And Windows platform [have](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740481%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) quite the same:

> Return value
>
> If no error occurs, shutdown returns zero. Otherwise, a value of
> SOCKET_ERROR is returned, and a specific error code can be retrieved
> by calling WSAGetLastError.

Thing is: UDP is not connection oriented protocol and connect() call for it do not mean that any association is established whatsoever.

So my guess, you're actually getting ENOTCONN error (or WSAENOTCONN, if you're on Windows)
Check your errno (or  WSAGetLastError() on Windows)

Comment: you have talked of shutdown() return code but what I want is concerned with closure or shutdown of socket  , I should get 0 as the return code from recvfrom() call , since the socket descriptor is no longer there on the sender side.

Comment: @javabinder He is talking about it and you keep ignoring it. If you had *checked* the return code of shutdown() as you should have, you would have discovered that it did not succeed.

Comment: @EJP will check the same.. :)